# Need help Scripting configuration changes for Internet Option Advanced Settings

Tags: powershell, internet-explorer, registry

I am looking to change configuration settings for "turn on pop-up blocker" (privacy tab) and various advanced settings options, But I am at a loss For finding the desired registry locations.

After doing some digging i have found that the internet option settings are (generally) in this location:

```
'HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Main'
```

But beyond changing proxy configuration i have not found anything close to what i am looking for.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The registry location of pop-up blocker setting is here:

`HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\Zones\3`

You can new a DWORD value which **value name** is 1809, **value data** 0 means enable pop-up blocker and 3 means disable pop-up blocker.
You can refer to [this article](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/17479/windows-internet-explorer-11-change-security-privacy-settings) and [this post](https://community.spiceworks.com/topic/110179-ie-8-popup-blocker-won-t-turn-off) for detailed steps.